# How to fix path typos?

Tags: zsh, autocorrection

When typing quickly, I often mistype `cd ~/myfiles` as `cd ~?myfiles`, resulting in:

```
zsh: no matches found: ~?myfiles
```

Is there a way ZSH can autocorrect such mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, but you can write your own function for it:

```bsh
zle -N accept-line
accept-line() {
  BUFFER=${BUFFER/' ~?'/' ~/'}
  zle .accept-line
}
```

Whenever you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, this replaces the first occurrence of  `~?` with  `~/`, before executing the line.